# How to declare local "variables" as final in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, variables, final

In Java, I can declare local "variables" as final, e.g.

```
void myMethod() {
    final String foo = "Hello World!";
    foo = "Bye-bye..."; // compile error!!
    return;
}
```

When I try to change its value, a get an error from the compiler. I want to declare some of my local "variables" final to avoid changing their value by accident.

Is this possible in Objective-C?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like in C/C++, you can use the `const` keyword.

For more info, this article seems right up your alley: [Java Developer’s Guide to String Constants in Objective-C](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-string-constants-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't know that I could also use ``const`` in non-static declarations.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.